# XlsxWriter write data frame starting from specific cell

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm using `xlsxwriter` to create an Excel file. Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

datetime_format = workbook.add_format({
    'font_size': 12
})
worksheet.write('C2', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), datetime_format)

# Rest removed for brevity. I simply have many stuff that 
# I manually write to make the design as I want.

workbook.close()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
result.to_excel(writer, startrow=6, startcol=3) # Start from D7.
writer.save()
```

Now, this seems to rewrite everything that I previously wrote manually using `xlsxwriter`. Also, I noticed that `xlsxwriter` does not have support by default to write data frames, am I right? How can I combine `xlsxwriter` and `pandas` to manually write some stuff to do Excel sheet, and then later to write all the data frame stuff starting from the specific cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shift things around. I would also recommend to read the [XlsWritter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) on how to use it with pandas.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook = writer.book

result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=6, startcol=3) # Start from D7.

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

datetime_format = workbook.add_format({
    'font_size': 12
})
worksheet.write('C2', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), datetime_format)

writer.save()
```

First, we create our writer object using `pd.ExcelWriter()` and passing `xlswriter` as the engine. Once we have our writer we can access our workbook using the `.book` class vriable. At this time, we can write our data into our workbook using `df.to_excel()`. We will use the `sheet_name` argument of `to_excel` to create and name our worksheet. At this point we can acess our worksheet using the `.sheets` class variable and passing our sheetname as a key - in our case `Sheet1`.

From there you can write additional values to your sheet with or without using a pandas object - as shown in the code below.